# Error in updating single property of an entity using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have following Entity:

```
public class Document
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Number { get; set; }
   public int Version { get; set; }
   //other properties with [Required]
}
```

I wrote a method to update **only** `Version` of one `Document`:

```
public void SetDocumentVersion(int docId, int version)
{
   var doc = new Document() { Id = docId, Version= version };
   using (var db = new MyEfContextName())
   {
     db.Documents.Attach(doc);
     db.Entry(doc).Property(x => x.Version).IsModified = true;
     db.SaveChanges();   //<--- get error
}
```

}

But when I run the method I get following Error:

> The Number field is required.

Is there any way to bypass this validation?

Comment: assign value to Number property while creating instance of Document class. You can see Number field is decorated with `[Required]`attribute. Error message is self explanatory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable validation on saving changes like this (do this before calling `SaveChanges`):

```
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Then it should work as you would expect (generate `UPDATE` query for just `Version` column).

Answer (score 0):

Either remove `[Required]` attribute to Number property from Document class or assign value to `Number` property while creating instance of Document class

First approach:

```
public class Document
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   //[Required] /*Remove this attribute*/
   public string Number { get; set; }
   public int Version { get; set; }
   //other properties
}
```

---

If you can't remove `[Required]` from model, then assign some value to Number

```
var doc = new Document() { Id = docId, Version= version, Number = "NotNullStringValue" };
```

More about [required attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/required-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a value to the Number field.

```
var doc = new Document() { Id = docId, Version= version, Number = "SomeValue" };
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when using Data Annotations on classes that form the tables within your database they are translated into constraints. The Required annotation translates to NOT NULL meaning a value must be supplied.

Remove the Required annotation if you wish the field to be nullable or supply a value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx